# How to create a dictionary where the keys are the elements in a list and the values are numbers from 1 to n?

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a list l1 = [a,b,c,d,e] and I want to map it to a dictionary that would contain the following {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5}

I know how to do it in a very naive way, but I would like something more 'pythonic'

The naive way:

```
dic = {}
j = 1
for i in list1:
    dic[i] = j
    j += 1
```

Comment: You can `enumerate(l1)` and reverse or `dict(zip(l1, itertools.count(1)))`

Comment: Now it does. Deal with it

Comment: Well, still causes `NameError: name 'list1' is not defined`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann If you are so concerned about the construction of the question, you may edit it (if you can) as you please. Don't forget to drink your milk. bye

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {v: k for k, v in enumerate(l1, 1)}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
```

Comment: @ChristianDean that's very true, however I prefer to be more explicit in line with [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python)

Comment: I'll just have to agree to disagree. Saying you want `enumerate()` to explicitly start at `1` is explicit, `k+1` is magic and has a redundant addition.

Comment: @AChampion that's a fair argument, but I'm not sure why you'd think `k + 1` is magic?

Comment: Magic maybe strong, but personally I find it requires more interpreting.

Comment: That's very pythonic, thank you. But, see, the list contains strings that are sorted in alphabetic order and their values are not ordered as well, like:

{'a':3, 'b':1, 'c':2} any idea why is this happening?

Comment: @StefanPochmann, Yeah I just realized I've erased the sorting line in my code. My bad.

Comment: @AChampion Exactly. Thanks. Took the works out of my mouth.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make up for the flub earlier... You can use the `dict` type constructor with `itertools.count` and `zip`:

```
>>> L1 = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> from itertools import count
>>> dict(zip(L1, count(1)))
{'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: @AChampion **damn**

Comment: Hehe, just need `count(1)`. OP's code starts at `0` but the text asks to start at `1`.

Comment: @AChampion a *very long* day.